# How to add two inputs (start date and end date)

Tags: angular, typescript

Good evening,

I have a webService that returns data which I display in an HTML table.
As I have a lot of rows in my table, I would like to use 2 inputs to filter the dates.

[image]

In the **service.ts** file I call a webservice to display the data in the html table.

```
@Injectable()
export class HistoricalPricesService {
  private readonly api: string = environment.api;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private datePipe: NekorFormatDatePipe) { }
 
  getInstrumentHistoryEquities(svm: string, model: ReturnModel): Observable<InstrumentHistoryResponse> {
    const now = new Date();
    const lastYear = new Date();
    lastYear.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() - 1);
 
    return this.http.post<InstrumentHistoryResponse>(this.api + `/WEBSERVICETITRE`, {
      SVM: parseInt(svm),
        PERIODE: 'XX',
        PERIODEXX: {
          DATEDEBUT: this.datePipe.transform(model.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          DATEFIN: this.datePipe.transform(model.endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        }
    }, { headers: { DoNotSetBusy: '' } });
  }
}
```

Then I created a **return-model.ts** file for the two inputs (start date and end date).

```
export class ReturnModel {
    startDate: Date;
    endDate?: Date;
 
    constructor() {
        this.endDate = new Date();
        this.startDate = new Date();
        this.startDate.setFullYear(this.endDate.getFullYear() - 5);
    }
 
    verifyStart(): void {
        if (this.endDate && (this.startDate >= this.endDate)) {
            this.endDate = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

The **historical-prices.component.ts** file

```
export class HistoricalPricesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
 
  infoTitle: string = "";
  historicals: Tit;
  lines: HistoryPoint[] = [];
 
  model = new ReturnModel();
 
  constructor(
    private service: HistoricalPricesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
    if (!svm) {
      return;
    }
    this.getPrices(svm);
  }
 
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
 
  //Display data // 
  getPrices(svm: string): void {
    this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(svm,this.model,).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
          this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
 
          console.log("Display => " + JSON.stringify(res.HISTO.POINT));
        }
      }
    });
  }
 
}
```

On the console.log I retrieve the data

[image]

If I click from my browser on Network > Payload

I can clearly see the 2 inputs (start date and end date)

[image]

Now my problem is that I really don't understand what I have to do in the getPrices() method to fit the 2 inputs?

```
getPrices(svm: string): void {
    this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(svm,this.model,).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
          this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
 
          console.log("Display => " + JSON.stringify(res.HISTO.POINT));
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

At the HTML level, I currently have this with an error message....

```
<form #formulaire="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formulaire.form.valid && getPrices()">
<div class="row mb-4 align-items-end">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <h5>
            Date de départ
         </h5>
         <input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="text" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.startDate" bsDatepicker />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <h5>
            Date de fin
         </h5>
         <input id="endDate" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control form-max-width" [(ngModel)]="model.endDate" bsDatepicker />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="mb-2">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="formulaire.form.invalid">
         Rechercher 
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your `getPrices()` function expects one argument.

It seems like you might want to store `svm` at class level, for example:

`private svm: string;`

And then change your `getPrices()` method to use the `svm` class property:

```
getPrices(): void {
    this.service.getInstrumentHistoryEquities(this.svm,this.model).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        if (res.HISTO.POINT.length > 0) {
          this.lines = res.HISTO.POINT.reverse();
 
          console.log("Display => " + JSON.stringify(res.HISTO.POINT));
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem is that I absolutely have to keep the svm because it is an `id`. If you have a solution, I'm interested. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely - are you expecting the value of `svm` to change after the initial load? If not then the above solution should function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

make it optional!
getPrices(svm?: string), you can avoid the error of expecting 1 argument but got 0 by making it optional.